# Alternative way of developing for ASP.NET to WebForms - Any problems with this?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

So I have been developing in ASP.NET WebForms for some time now but often get annoyed with all the overhead (like ViewState and all the JavaScript it generates), and the way WebForms takes over a lot of the HTML generation.

Sometimes I just want full control over the markup and produce efficient HTML of my own so I have been experimenting with what I like to call **HtmlForms**.

Essentially this is using ASP.NET WebForms but without the form `runat="server"` tag. Without this tag, ASP.NET does not seem to add anything to the page at all. From some basic tests it seems that it runs well and you still have the ability to use code-behind pages, and many ASP.NET controls such as repeaters.

Of course without the form `runat="server"` many controls won't work. A post at [Enterprise Software Development](http://www.devprise.com/2007/06/07/aspnet-what-server-side-controls-require-a-server-form/) lists the controls that do require the tag.

From that list you will see that all of the form elements like TextBoxes, DropDownLists, RadioButtons, etc cannot be used. Instead you use normal HTML form controls. But how do you access these HTML controls from the code behind?

Retrieving values on post back is easy, you just use `Request.QueryString` or `Request.Form`.

But passing data to the control could be a little messy. Do you use a ASP.NET Literal control in the value field or do you use `<%= value %>` in the markup page? I found it best to add `runat="server"` to my HTML controls and then you can access the control in your code-behind like this: `((HtmlInputText)txtName).Value = "blah"`;

Here's a example that shows what you can do with a textbox and drop down list:

**Default.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="NoForm.Default" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <label for="txtName">Name:</label>
        <input id="txtName" name="txtName" runat="server" /><br />
        <label for="ddlState">State:</label>
        <select id="ddlState" name="ddlState" runat="server">
            <option value=""></option>
        </select><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
namespace NoForm
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Default values
            string name = string.Empty;
            string state = string.Empty;
            if (Request.RequestType == "POST")
            {
                //If form submitted (post back)
                name = Request.Form["txtName"];
                state = Request.Form["ddlState"];
                //Server side form validation would go here
                //and actions to process form and redirect
            }
            ((HtmlInputText)txtName).Value = name;
            ((HtmlSelect)ddlState).Items.Add(new ListItem("ACT"));
            ((HtmlSelect)ddlState).Items.Add(new ListItem("NSW"));
            ((HtmlSelect)ddlState).Items.Add(new ListItem("NT"));
            ((HtmlSelect)ddlState).Items.Add(new ListItem("QLD"));
            ((HtmlSelect)ddlState).Items.Add(new ListItem("SA"));
            ((HtmlSelect)ddlState).Items.Add(new ListItem("TAS"));
            ((HtmlSelect)ddlState).Items.Add(new ListItem("VIC"));
            ((HtmlSelect)ddlState).Items.Add(new ListItem("WA"));
            if (((HtmlSelect)ddlState).Items.FindByValue(state) != null)
                ((HtmlSelect)ddlState).Value = state;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, you have similar functionality to ASP.NET server controls but more control over the final markup, and less overhead like ViewState and all the JavaScript ASP.NET adds.

Interestingly you can also use HttpPostedFile to handle file uploads using your own input type="file" control (and necessary form enctype="multipart/form-data").

So my question is can you see any problems with this method, and any thoughts on it's usefulness?

I have further details and tests on [my blog](http://blog.johnavis.com/blog/default.asp?id=609).

Comment: There's this wonderful thing called MVC and Razor syntax. Check it out.

Comment: Definitely found Razor to generate cleaner client side stufflez in my observations...

Comment: Does this code honestly look good to you? To me it looks like an ill-conceived knock-off of MVC, carelessly mixing HTML semantics with code-behind (not to mention an insane amount of casting) instead of just sticking to either the MVC paradigm of models and templating or the webforms paradigm of control trees. Not wanting to sound like a grumpy old fart here, but I just would not want to touch that code, ever.

Comment: what you are doing is anti-pattern. For truly stateless and fast web-development you may simply consider http://www.asp.net/mvc - which will resolve all your challenges elegantly. In addition, MVC framework is open-source !

Comment: I don't see the advantage of this code.  It looks like it will be very hard to maintain.  It seems like your inexperience in this field has lead you to solve a problem that your not experienced enough to solve yourself.  There is nothing wrong with Javascript there is a reason it is used.

Comment: I thought about cooking up this kind of pattern myself, when I first started doing lots of WebForms work and disliked the hijacking of my HTML & JavaScript. But don't do it. Either go ASP.NET MVC, or learn how to embrace WebForms. Honestly, the speed you gain with a databound GridView can often outweigh the pain you feel when you View Source.

Comment: I have looked at MVC and can't say that I like it (I know I must be in the minority). I have done some work in "ASP.NET Web Pages" using Razor syntax and I do like it as reminds me of developing in Classic ASP but with the .NET advantages. @Ramhound, I do know the advantages of JavaScript but I object to having so many includes - I would like to minimise the number of HTTP requests. In fact I like JavaScript a lot and would prefer to write my own instead of have ASP.NET do it for me.

Comment: What don't you like about MVC? You have complete control over everything in MVC.. from the controller factory to the markup that is generated..

Comment: @John, disregard ANY MVC tutorial that has 'real' code in the View. Use the "Fat Model/Thin Controller/Stupid View" paradigm and MVC will really shine.

Comment: @Graham, do you know of any tutorials for this paradigm? I Googled but didn't see anything obvious.

Comment: Just adjust your google search, here's a phrase that brings back a lot: https://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=fat+model+skinny+controller

Comment: Its a simple enough concept. Controllers should ONLY know enough to know which ViewModels to instantiate, and maybe know 1-2 methods to call on each. All the 'real' work is done in the ViewModel methods, not the Controller actions. If your Controller Actions start getting longer than a couple lines, refactor it into the ViewModel. The Views themselves should be very, very dumb. Turn as much into strings as you can before sending it into the View, don't do much logic in the View (simple IF's on ViewModel props are OK).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problems that I see:

- **Non-standard way of working**: you are coming up with your own, fairly non-standard way of working.  Any new developers you hire will have to learn the details of your framework.  Some of them may not like it (e.g. see some of the comments above), and refuse to work in it.  As you go along, you will also keep (re-)inventing lots of basic functionality, like data-binding, which is essentially a waste of your efforts.
- **Not using the technology's strengths**: WebForms are an attempt to bring event-driven programming to the web.  To enable this by default, a lot of state has to be passed around all the time.  By working around this, you are losing most of the functionality and benefits of WebForms.
- **Existing technologies that do this already**: There are excellent technologies that do what you are trying to do, but in a much better way.  ASP.Net MVC is probably the best known.  If you would like to develop in a style that is closer to the way the web actually works (and would like a framework which helps in that), try it.  It really is an excellent technology, a bit of fresh air compared to WebForms.

Comment: You make some good points.

Comment: @John thanks, and BTW, people have long been trying to get WebForms to be a bit more "light" in a similar way to yours.  Most typically end up switching off ViewState (and managing it themselves, similar to you), or doing tricks like storing it on the server (session, file, DB, whatever - [examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733542/viewstate-alternatives-in-asp-net-webforms)) so it doesn't get passed around. I've just found that the results aren't great for the amount of work you have to put in, compared with existing frameworks.